# Django QuerySet First in Group

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a queryset that looks like:

```
{id, group_id, date}
```

For each group, keyed by the `group_id`, I'd like to return the `id` with the earliest `date`. How would I do that in a django query? Or is it more efficient to order_by date and then use a python dict to ignore all elements with the same group_id after the first?

Answer (score 4):

Django doesn't really have the `GROUP BY` operator.  You could try to mimic it with ordering and `distinct()`.

Try something like this:

```
queryset.order_by('group_id', 'date').distinct('group_id')
```

Note: that the `group_id` has to be first in the ordering to perform the `distinct()` operation.

Comment: Kevin, I tried that and two errors arose. One was a TypeError: expected string or buffer when I tried order_by with both group_id and date (although singly they each work). Another was that I couldn't do distinct('group_id') and instead found a workaround with values_list('group_id', flat=True).distinct(). Any idea about the first?

Comment: Ahh, I see, the brackets aren't needed. I bumped you both. Thanks Kevin.

Comment: Sorry, worked off memory, yeah, no brackets, updated.