# Django ORM query for month and year

Tags: python, django, django-models

how to make an ORM query with month and year of datefield.

```
select sum(price) from mytable group by month(start_date),year(start_date);
```

The above query which is giving the exact result. But in the ORM i  tried but how to group by month and year wise.

My ORM query

```
 rv_per_month = Price_Report.objects.filter(item__in=item_Arr).aggregate(Sum('revenue'))
```

The above orm query which is giving the sum(price) . But I want it as group by month and year

Comment: Please show your ORM query, thx.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20806345/django-queryset-first-in-group

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746014/django-group-sales-by-month

Comment: @chandu Could you please post a orm query to the answer section

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from decimal import Decimal
qs = Price_Report.objects.values_list("created_at", "amount")
tmp = defaultdict(Decimal)
for date, amount in qs:
   tmp[date.year, date.month] += amount
```

Comment: I have tried it say's Cannot resolve keyword 'year' into field. Join on 'start_date' not permitted.

Comment: You can group you amount in python

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.